# Show convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

The following series converges when $|x| < 1$:

\begin{align*}
   \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n x^n \\
\end{align*}

Show that it converges to:

\begin{align*}
     \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}\\=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \ \mbox{for} \ |x|<1$$
Now, in general, interchange of differentiation and infinite summation is not allowed, but for a power series, this is allowed within the radius of convergence. This means that for $|x|<1$ (which is indeed within the radius of convergence):
$$x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}x^n\\=x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}\\
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}\\
=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \ \mbox{(from earlier)}$$

Comment: Note that you're allowed to derive because the series converges uniformly in the radius of convergence.